# How to get a warning, if the C Code comparing different datatypes?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I want to see a warning or an error if the developer in C Code is comparing different data types. I am using the gcc arm none eabi and I have tried the following code and the following compiler flags correspondingly.

```
uint8_t foo = 0;
int16_t bar = -1;

int main() {
  while(1) {
    if (foo==bar) return 0;
  }
}
```

Compiler Options

```
-Wsign-compare -Wall -Wextra
```

But I cannot see any error or warning, Why? Could you help me?

Comment: The values are promoted to `int` before comparison; they have the same type when promoted.  That may be why you don’t get any warning for the comparison. You should get a warning about the `return` with no value in a function returning an `int`, unless perhaps the compiler deduces the return will never be executed.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options "*`-Wsign-compare` - Warn when a comparison between signed and unsigned values could produce an incorrect result when the signed value is converted to unsigned.*" `bar` is not converted to an unsigned type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the reply, but I want to deny the developers to use this kind of comparison. Maybe this code is simple but in complex software maybe it will be a very awful bug.

Comment: `-Wsign-compare` is only for C++

Comment: @melpomene could you explain more about your answer?

Comment: @KeineLust Documentation seems to imply that it's available also on C: *"-Wsign-compare

    Warn when a comparison between signed and unsigned values could produce an incorrect result when the signed value is converted to unsigned. In C++, this warning is also enabled by -Wall. **In C, it is also enabled by -Wextra.**
"*

Comment: @KeineLust How could I use in C something similar?

Comment: @poprock 1) I only wrote a comment, not an answer. 2) What's unclear about it?

Comment: @KeineLust No, it's also for C. See, see the manual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wsign-compare

Comment: @melpomene why is not converted to an unsigned type?

Comment: What about an analyse tool like PC-Lint?

Comment: Oops, sorry, `-Wall` turns on this flag only in C++

Comment: @poprock because `uint8_t` and `int16_t` both fit into `int`, therefore they'll be promoted to int. And it's *promotion*, not *conversion*. All types narrower than int will always be promoted to int

Comment: @poprock Because, as JonathanLeffler said, they're both converted to `int`. As for why, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/1848654.

Comment: @phuclv Are you sure that is it ok? I mean, it is safe for the software or maybe in complex situations exist an awful bug?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler *You should get a warning ...*  Not on `main()`.  Per [**5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3): "... reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0 ..."

Comment: This should be caught in static analysis, for example: http://adlint.sourceforge.net/pmwiki/upload.d/Main/users_guide_en.html#W0245

Comment: @AndrewHenle — Before it was edited, the return after the if had no value specified. I agree that if the infinite loop terminates, falling off the end of main in C99 or later is equivalent to returning zero.

Comment: There's nothing dangerous with *comparing different datatypes* per se. People compare like that all the time, for example int and long. It's just that comparing **types with different signness** may produce unexpected result due to the change in *value*, and that was coverered with `-Wsign-compare`. In this case all the values are preserved like chux said, and the output won't surprise you like `-1 > 2U`

Answer (score 2):

> How to get a warning, if the C Code comparing different datatypes?

`==` causes both operands to to go though an *implicit conversion* per their relative *integer conversion rank*.  To get a warning, do a comparison that after *integer promotions*, the operands differ in sign-ness.

> > If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.  C11dr §6.3.1.1 2

A key concept to remember is that *integer promotions* never changes the *value*, only the *type*.  With no value change, the compare happens with no "surprises".

It is conversion that may change the *value*.  E.g. `int -1` --> `unsigned UINT_MAX`.

---

> I cannot see any error or warning, Why?

With `foo8 == bar` below, both `foo8` and `bar` are promoted to `int`.  **There is nothing significant to warn about**.  The compare is well defined for all value combinations of `bar, foo8` - no surprises.  That is C.

```
uint8_t foo8 = 0;
int16_t bar = -1;
uint32_t foo32 = 0;

int main(void) {
  if (foo8 == bar)  return 1;
  if (foo32 == bar) return 2;
}
```

With `foo32 == bar`,  `foo32` becomes `unsigned` (or `unsigned long`) and `bar` is promoted to `int`.  With various compiler options, you can readily get a warning like

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

---

In this later case, to compare an `int` over its [INT_MIN...INT_MAX] range to an `unsigned` over its [0...UINT_MAX] range and make sure comparing `-1, UINT_MAX` fails, code could use:

```
// if (foo32 == bar) return 2;
if (bar >= 0 && foo32 == (unsigned)bar) return 2;
```